# Code blocks rendering bug in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, markdown-rendering

As we all know, inline code blocks like `this one` have got a fixed-width font and a light grey background to distinguish them easily.

By the way I recently answered a question on Stack Overflow, and noticed a strange behavior of code blocks on my SE iOS app. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804295/3889449), **some of them are shown without the usual grey background**. It looks like there are just two lonely code blocks suffering from this issue, while the other ones are rendered correctly.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image: screenshot]

They're rendered perfectly on the main site, you can check it by yourself, so I assume this is an issue only regarding the iOS app.

---

**Thechnical info**:

- Stack Exchange iOS app v1.3.0
- Apple iPhone 4S running iOS 7.1.2

Comment: yup. broken here too

Comment: I see what I did.  I'm doing  `p code { background-color: #eee; }` and the markdown parser doesn't inject a paragraph-tags for lists with one only one item.

Comment: @BrianNickel oh here it is! Cool to hear the developer himself! Would you mind turning that into an answer so I can accept it and mark the question as [status-planned] or [status-completed]?

Comment: I will when I complete it. 

Comment: @BrianNickel good to know! Thanks for your work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

We actually use a slightly lighter background color in our code blocks (what's with devs and designers picking so many arbitrary shades of gray?) as well as different padding, so I limited the styling on inline code to:

```
p code {
    background-color: #eee; padding: 1px 5px;
}
```

Of course I forgot certain Markdown lists don't have paragraphs:

- `In a paragraph.`
- `In a paragraph.`

1. `Not in a paragraph.`

- `Not in a paragraph.`

Since the colors for a code block are applied to the `pre`, I just did this:

```
code {
    background-color: #eee; padding: 1px 5px;
}

pre code {
    background-color: transparent; padding: 0;
}
```